# Прописные буквы в названиях монашеских/духовных/рыцарских и прочих орденов

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, названия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишутся названия монашеских/духовных/рыцарских орденов, где нужны прописные буквы? Например: орден рыцарей Тлеющей Свечи, орден Чёрной Пантеры, рыцари Багряного Заката... "Грамота.ру" меня подзапутала. Смотрите, как они отвечают.

1. Вроде бы есть правило (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=266957)).

**Вопрос № 266957**

> Уважаемая "Грамота", верно ли написание: Орден Рыцарей Госпитальеров?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Подобные названия духовно-рыцарских и монашеских организаций пишутся строчными: *орден тамплиеров*, *орден госпитальеров*, *орден рыцарей-госпитальеров*, *орден бенедиктинцев* (но: *орден Гроба Господня*, *орден рыцарей Храма*; *Ливонский орден*, *Тевтонский орден* — собственные имена в составе названия пишутся с прописной). См.: Лопатин В. В., Нечаева И. В., Чельцова Л. К. Прописная или строчная? Орфографический словарь. М., 2011.

2. Однако один из ответов этому правилу противоречит (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=251936)).

**Вопрос № 251936**

> Орден (религиозный, братство) Рыцарей Колумба. Надо ли писать орден и рыцарей с прописной?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Корректное написание: *орден Рыцарей Колумба*.

3. А тут так (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=291128)).

**Вопрос № 291128**

> "Рыцари круглого стола" - нужно ли "круглого" или "стола" писать с заглавной буквы?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Верно: *рыцари Круглого стола*.

Так как же правильно, где действительно нужны прописные и почему?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуем разобраться. Исхожу из положения, что "орден", "орден рыцарей" и "братство" — это родовые термины. Согласно общему правилу, они пишутся со строчной буквы. А дальше предлагаю рассмотреть нюансы.

1. Если в начале названия находится слово "орден", то оно пишется со строчной буквы (орден Гроба Господня, орден Чёрной Пантеры).
2. Если в начале названия ордена находится другое слово, то оно пишется с прописной, но само слово "орден" всё равно со срочной (Тевтонский орден, Ливонский орден) .
3. Если в названии ордена используется имя собственное (в т.ч. названия святынь, организаций и др.), то оно пишется с прописной буквы (орден Чёрной Пантеры, орден Гроба Господня).
4. Титулы, вроде "рыцарей", пишутся со строчной буквы ("Рыцари Колумба" исключение, поскольку это дословное название ордена: оно начинается со слова "Рыцари". Здесь будет правильно сказать не "орден рыцарей Колумба" и даже не "орден Рыцарей Колумба", а "орден Рыцари Колумба", ср. "Свидетели Иеговы", которые также пишутся с заглавной только потому, что "свидетели" являются первым словом имени собственном религиозной организации, если бы они располагались, например, вторым словом, то писались бы с прописной).

"Круглый стол", по видимому, как реальный уникальный физический объект, имеет одну прописную букву в начале названия, поскольку стол был и остаётся столом (ср. Ниагарский водопад, Эйфелева башня и др.)

Откуда взяты примеры с орденом Чёрной Пантеры, Багряного Заката и Тлеющей Свечи, не представляю. Однако вполне логично, что здесь с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, поскольку это не реальные физические пантера, закат и свеча, а названия (т.е. своего рода имена, просто принадлежащие предметам и состоящие больше, чем из одного слова).

Резюмируя:

Если назвать орден: "орден рыцарей Пизанской башни", то с прописной будет только первая буква имени собственного, а рыцари и башня — это простые существительные.
Если назвать орден: "Рыцари Пизанской башни", то рыцари будут с прописной, поскольку это первая буква в имени собственном.
Если назвать орден: "орден рыцарей Зелёного Копья", то с прописной будут оба последних слова, поскольку они составляют метафорическое название, а не указывают на конкретный предмет.

Единственный пример, который не вписывается в эту логику, — "Орден бедных Рыцарей Христа" (Christi pauperum Militum Ordo). Не берусь судить, копать лень. Но предположу, что там может присутствовать преемственность названий от более старых орденов. По крайней мере, не вижу ни одной логической причины писать название именно таким образом.